# Woocommerce disable product variations if already in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a small script trying to exclude WC product variations which are already in the cart on a product variation, available to buy.

The below script is working if there is 1 variation in the cart, thus disabling that variation on product page. But when more variations are added in the cart these timeslots remain possible. Anyone see what i am missing here?

Script idea: All WC products have the same variation possibility (timeslot + day)

1. GET variations of all products currently in the user cart
2. GET product variations of CURRENT product EXCEPT the variation combinations in the cart
3. SHOW remaining variation a user can select, no overlap is possible with the timeslots in the cart

```
// 1st part - get current variations from products_in_cart() {
  $products_in_cart = array();
  $cart_items =  WC()->cart->get_cart();
  //
  foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item ){
    if ($cart_item['product_id']) {
      //$products_in_cart[] = $cart_item['variation_id'];
      //$products_in_cart[] = $cart_item['variation'];
      $exclude = implode(' ', $cart_item['variation']);
      echo '<font color="red">Combi in cart: ' . $exclude . '</font><br/>';
    }
  }

  if (count($products_in_cart) > 0) {}
//print_r ($products_in_cart);

// 2nd part of the script; comparing variations in cart to current product view variations
 //function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
 global $product, $post;
 $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
 ?>
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
    $possibleoption = implode(' ', $value['attributes']);
    //if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
    if(!empty($value['attributes']) AND ($possibleoption != $exclude)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>
            <?php
            echo $possibleoption;
            ?>
            </b>
        </td>
        <td>
          
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
            <?php
            if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
            foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></button>
            </form>
 
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>
            <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
            </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
<?php
 //}
```

Live script (choose one and add to cart, use only the buttons):
https://app.sportenbewegenhilversum.nl/product-categorie/keuzedelen/

[Image explaining frontend situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbUax.png)